# Blender script error: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Tags: python, scripting

I was working on a project to automate a few things. I have written a Python script that does the following steps:

1. opens blender scene file
2. imports the FBX model
3. assigns the material
4. combines the object to one part
5. renders the scene

The script performs a few tasks when I execute it, but when it comes to combining the objects in step 04, it throws an error: **Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\Text", line 57, in 
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\3.3\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in **call**
ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect**

I researched the solution to the error, and I found that keeping the objects active solves the issue (as per line 54), but in my case it did not. However, once it throws an error and I re-execute the same code from the last line from where it was stopped, it works correctly. Is it due to an active or inactive viewport?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import bpy
import os

# set paths------------------------------Step 0
folder = "E:\\\\Other\\\\Blender\\\\646dd9a82eb3b5000899b027\\\\"
output_path = "E:/Other/Blender/646dd9a82eb3b5000899b027/Output"
model = folder+"Model.fbx"
scene_path = folder+"Scene.blend"

# Open Scene------------------------------ Step 01
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=scene_path)

# Import FBX------------------------------ Step 02
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = model )

importedObjects = [ o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.select_get()]

# apply checkerboard material to all objects------------------------------Step 03
## Remove all current materials from selected objects
for obj in importedObjects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        for mat_slot in obj.material_slots:
            bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({"object": obj})

## Create a new BSDF material
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="chkrbrd_Mat")
mat.use_nodes = True

## Add a diffuse bitmap node and link it to the BSDF material
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
links = mat.node_tree.links

image_path = folder + 'Checkerboard2.jpeg'

diffuse_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexImage")
diffuse_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(image_path)
bsdf_node = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")

links.new(diffuse_node.outputs[0], bsdf_node.inputs[0])

## Assign the material to selected objects
for obj in importedObjects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        obj.data.materials.append(mat)

#Combine Objects and provide new name to object------------------------------Step 04
##Combine Objects
for ob in importedObjects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        ob.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    else:
        ob.select = False
bpy.ops.object.join()
##Rename the object
for obj in importedObjects:
    obj.name = "p9Box1_product"

# Render All scene cameras in scene------------------------------Step 05
obj_in_scene = bpy.context.scene.collection.all_objects
cameras = [obj for obj in obj_in_scene if obj.type == 'CAMERA']

# Loop through all the cameras in the scene
obj_in_scene = bpy.context.scene.collection.all_objects
cameras = [obj for obj in obj_in_scene if obj.type == 'CAMERA']

# Loop through all the cameras in the scene
for cams in cameras:
    # Set the active camera to the current camera
    bpy.context.scene.camera = cams

    # Set the output filename to be the name of the current camera
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path + cams.name + ".jpg"

    # Set the resolution to 1024x1024
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 1024
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 1024

    # Set the file format to JPEG
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'

    # Render the scene and save it to the output folder with the name of the current camera
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Looking forward to the solution.